# how to use showFromTabBar with tabbed application in Interface Builder?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitabbar

I'm using an action sheet in my tabbed application, and when it shows, Xcode logs the following message:

Presenting action sheet clipped by its superview. Some controls might not respond to touches. 
On iPhone try

```
-[UIActionSheet showFromTabBar:]
```

or

```
-[UIActionSheet showFromToolbar:]
```

instead of

```
-[UIActionSheet showInView:].
```

But `showFromTabBar` takes a `UITabBar` argument, and the `UITabBar`set up in the Interface Builder (tab bar controller or view controller, doesn't matter) won't connect to any `UITabBar` I create in any header file.  So I can't call `showFromTabBar` on the tab bar I actually have.

Any suggestions about how to proceed?

Comment: Thanks--that worked!  Can you give it as an answer so I can upvote and accept it and give you points?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can give `self.tabbarcontroller.tabbar` as input parameter

Answer (score 2):

If it is a tabbed application, you will get Interface Builder's tabBar instance by invoking this

```
 self.tabBarController.tabBar
```

property. So you can do like this

```
[yourActionSheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];
```

to show UIActionSheet.